# RSpec - Get number of errors that have occurred thus far

Tags: rspec

Is there a way to access or tally the number of failures that have occurred at a particular  point?  For example at the end of my first describe block I want to see how many failures have occurred.  I know it prints at the end but I want it *now* :)

Comment: This question is a duplicate. See the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250972/getting-rspec-to-report-intermediate-failures