# Getting RSpec to report intermediate failures

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Is there a way to get RSpec to report failures as they occur, instead of the long list of green/red dots?
I'm running RSpec 2.5.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSpec supports multiple output formats, specified with the `--format` option. The default is "progress", the string of dots you're seeing. If you change to a more verbose format, you'll see the name of the test in red/green as you run, but you still won't see what the failure was until the summary that's printed at the end.

The other format options, from running `rspec --help` are:

```
-f, --format FORMATTER           Choose a formatter
                                   [p]rogress (default - dots)
                                   [d]ocumentation (group and example names)
                                   [h]tml
                                   [t]extmate
                                   custom formatter class name
```

In addition to specifying format on the command line, you can put a ".rspec" file in your home directory to specify default options.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [different format](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/command-line/format-option), such as `--format documentation`.

You can pass it as argument to the CLI.

```
$ rspec spec/ --format documentation
```

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the different formatters out there. I guess the one you are looking for is `FailingExamplesFormatter` to be run just like this:

```
spec spec --require spec/runner/formatter/failing_examples_formatter.rb --formatter FailingExamplesFormatter
```